# React Syncing element from Virtual DOM with element from HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react component which contains a 3D animation with playback controls (pause/play) inside a HTML page and I need the controls to be synced with some buttons outside the react component.
The controls in react are implemented like this

```
<Button  color='red' onClick={() => { setDataPlayback(false); }} >  <Icon name='pause' /></Button>
<Button color='red' onClick={() => { setDataPlayback(true); }} >  <Icon name='play' /> </Button>
```

and the buttons in the html page are

```
<div id="btns">
    <button id="html-button-pause" onclick="python_function_pause()"></button>
    <button id="html-button-play" onclick="python_function_play()"></button>
</div>
```

So whenever I press a button in react, I want it to trigger a click on the html button.

Comment: try  document.getElementById("html-button-pause").click()

Comment: Thanks @monesulhaque, this worked just fine :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<Button  color='red' onClick={() => { setDataPlayback(false); python_function_pause(); }} >  <Icon name='pause' />
```

And the same for the other button. You can invoke `click` of an HTML element programmatically using `.click()` function. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp).